# Adding an app to a new page tab?

Tags: facebook, tabs

I'm sorry for asking a really stupid question, but since facebook changes its ways of developing and creating almost everything, I see no other way, but asking here.

I have a very simple task to perform, I created about 7 static HTML page on our server and I'd like to build them into an iframe, displayed in page tabs. So a New Tab for every page.

I allready created the tab, and the tab does pull the content from our server, but I have absolutely no Idea how to add this app to the page?

On the left side of the page, there allready are some frequently used apps, like flickr, rss-blog, youtube etc, if I click on "edit", I can only adjust those apps and remove them, but I have no possibility to add a new app. Am I missing anything? Every existing tutorial is about one or two years ol - and since facebook constantly changes those things, they are completely worthless.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=<app_id>&next=<app_url>
```